# Why is SourceConnectorConfig reported for sink connector?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to create a Kafka sink connector using the s[predfast s3 connector](https://github.com/spredfast/kafka-connect-s3).  However, for some reason, the log output is reporting a SourceConnectorConfig:

```
INFO ConnectorConfig values:
        connector.class = com.spredfast.kafka.connect.s3.sink.S3SinkConnector
        key.converter = null
        name = transactions-s3-sink
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = null
        value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig:180)
INFO Creating connector transactions-s3-sink of type com.spredfast.kafka.connect.s3.sink.S3SinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:178)
INFO Instantiated connector transactions-s3-sink with version 0.0.1 of type class com.spredfast.kafka.connect.s3.sink.S3SinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:181)
INFO Finished creating connector transactions-s3-sink (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:194)
INFO SourceConnectorConfig values:
        connector.class = com.spredfast.kafka.connect.s3.sink.S3SinkConnector
        key.converter = null
        name = transactions-s3-sink
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = null
        value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig:180)
INFO Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:824)
...
INFO Sink task WorkerSinkTask{id=transactions-s3-sink-0} finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:232)
```

Why is a SinkConnectorConfig reported yet further on in the log output I can see a WorkerSinkTask was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that this connector extends `Connector` abstract class instead of `SinkConnector` abstract class from Connect's API (see the source code [here](https://github.com/spredfast/kafka-connect-s3/blob/master/sink/src/main/java/com/spredfast/kafka/connect/s3/sink/S3SinkConnector.java#L17)).

Thus, Connect framework can't tell whether this connector is a source or a sink, and currently the logic in the code is that if it's not a sink, assume it's a source. That's why you experience this inconsistency.

The solution is for the connector to extend appropriate abstract class (here `org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkConnector`)